# XCode 5/ios7: gcno files missing

Tags: ios7, xcode5, xctest

For an iOS 7 application, after applying needed settings
'Generate Test Coverage Files == YES [debug only]
Instrument Program Flow == YES [debug only ]
Also added

```
__gcov_flush();
```

in tearDown in unit test class after declaring

```
 extern void __gcov_flush(void);
```

at the top in unit test .m file.

I am able to see the .gcda files generated for unit test classes but not 
a single .gcno files. i am using xctest framework. The project is initially
created in xcode 4.5.2 then updated to xcode 5. After updating to xcode 5, I replaced 
the sentestingkit.framework with xctest.framework. Also changed
wrapper extension from 'octest' to 'xctest'. Anybody do have any idea
why the .gcno files are not being generated even though the test are successfully compiled and run.

Answer (score 0):

`.gcno` files are generated during the compilation.